# Add to Timeline and Authorization issue

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, authorization, facebook-timeline

I have created a website where users can download albums after sharing the album on their timeline. The website can be found here at [skibsthekid](http://www.skibsthekid.com) (Music section for issue). The process requires that they "Add to Timeline" and then once authorizing the website to publish what they share, click the DOWNLOAD TO SHARE button which will publish an open graph object and start the download.

This works perfectly from my side and other developers. HOWEVER when a normal user tries this after click the "Add to Timeline" button the pop-up will simply take them to their facebook homepage. My open graph actions have been approved by facebook. Is there another approval process I need to go through or some error. I have tried to find the fault and nothing has come to light. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the application was in `Sandbox` Mode. However, when I tried to replicate the steps you provided above, the action worked for me. See the screenshot below for proof:

[image: Working Example]

Comment: Thanks mate, It was in sandbox mode. My fault there